# Write a text into text files causes blank space

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I was trying to save all the selected item in listbox into text file, but when I am saving the selected item, it will write some blank space then only save the selected item.

```
Else
            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, True)
                For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.SelectedItems.Count - 1
                    sw.WriteLine(Trim(ListBox2.SelectedItems(i)))


            Next
        End Using
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path, True)
            Do While sr.Peek >= 0
                newArray.Add(Trim(sr.ReadLine))
            Loop

        End Using
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, Trim(""))
        newArray.Sort()
        For Each line As String In newArray
            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, True)
                sw.WriteLine(Trim(line))
            End Using
        Next

    End If
```

[Blank Space in text files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2LVy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim tmpstr = ""
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path, True)
        Do While sr.Peek >= 0
            tmpstr = Trim(sr.ReadLine)
            If tmpstr.Length > 0 Then 'here is your problem
                newArray.Add() 
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
```

Comment: Adamn because i wanted to sort my text files everytime i saves item